# Trying to give a width using min-width to a th element

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xBsxH/3/) table, and I want to give a width to the second th element, but it doesn't work..

```
 <th style="min-width: 50px">
    Date from                                    
 </th>
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Your jsFiddle doesn't have `min-width`, but `width`. But its because that `th` is naturally wider than 50px anyway, change to 250px and you will see it changes

Comment: @Andy maybe i didn't explain very well. I just want to make a narrower column. In order to get it I have thought in modifying the width of the head of the column. My jsFiddle has now 50px (sorry I changed it for a while..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second (as well as the third) column contains `input` elements, and browsers make the column as wide as needed for them. You could prevent this by setting the column width explicitly *and* using `table-layout: fixed` on the `table` element, but this tends to cause serious trouble, and the cell content would either overflow or would have to be truncated.

So the best way is to set the width of the `input type=text` elements, adding the attribute `size=10` to them. To make the sizing more exact, consider setting `font-family: Consolas, monospace` in CSS for those elements. You won’t then need any explicit width settings for the column.

Answer (score 0):

you also can place a DIV-container in the TD-Element and set the min-width to the DIV. then you don't need table-layout:fixed. table-layout:fixed needs to set width and height to nearly every existing TD in the table. That's not very pretty...